# SKSpriteNodes Moving Direction

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

If I Have a SKSpriteNodes Moving From Right To Left With This Code

```
CGFloat distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + 2 * _pipeTexture1.size.width;
SKAction* movePipes = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMove y:0 duration:0.01 * distanceToMove];
SKAction* removePipes = [SKAction removeFromParent];
_movePipesAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[movePipes, removePipes]];
```

The Question Is How To Make These SKSpriteNodes Moving From ْUpper To Lower , What I Have To Use .Thanks

Comment: Hi, can't you just duplicate that same code but using heigth instead of width? and moving by Y instead of X? Please could you post more code?

Comment: `[SKAction moveByX:0 y:distanceToMove duration:durationToMove]`